# MySQL insert data not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have a file with 50000 rows. I make a code but it skips lots of row and pages.When i enter in phpmyadmin to look i have like so 1-10 then it start to skip 23-34 78 102 345 546 etc. i think i has something with the execution.

```
$contents = file_get_contents("testinsert.txt");
$data = explode(PHP_EOL, $contents);


$query = "INSERT INTO table (`name`) VALUES (?)";

$zz = $conn->prepare($query);

$zz ->bind_param("i", $bb);

$conn->query("START TRANSACTION");
foreach ($data as $bb) {
    $zz->execute();`
}

$zz->close();
$conn->query("COMMIT");
```

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a tool written in PHP, not a database into which you can insert data

Comment: Is the backtick really in your code, the one after `$zz->execute();\``

Comment: i know, it was just for explaing lol the data is worng phpmyadmin

Comment: **It would be useful to see some of the input file** as well as the code that is processing it

Comment: what is backtick ?

Comment: `backtick` The characters that you put around a table or column name in a query

Comment: i user varchar 255

Comment: backtick  = ` on my keyboard the character below ~

Answer (score 1):

I am amazed this code does anything: I would expect `$zz ->bind_param("i", $bb);` to be in the `foreach` loop. 
Also it would probably have to read:

```
foreach ($data as $bb) {
    $zz ->bind_param("s", $bb);
    $zz->execute();
}
```

(Notice the `s` for string data)

Comment: You would call `bind_param` outside the loop as the @OP did

Comment: @RamRaider That would only bind once and then on a not initialized variable (unless php has an unseen optimization for out of scope variables?)

Comment: do all of the "problem" rows have name field values?